# Roo Error need to Convert a Mail::Part to a file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, excel, email-attachments

I access an email attachment from an email (gmail) in ruby using `messages.attachments`

To access the first attachment I do `attachment = messages.attachment[0]`

This attachment is always going to be an .xslx file and when using the roo gem (parses excel) to access it and parse it I keep getting the error "can't convert Mail::Part into String"

What is Mail::Part and how can I convert this to a file or a path to a file Roo would understand

Answer (score 0):

A `Mail::Part` is really just a message. So, to get the (decoded) body of a part, do this:

```
attachment.body.decoded
```

Comment: I think you are right but I keep getting this error 'string contains null byte' after i make that change